# SQL Query to calculate change in amount

Tags: sql-server

Can anybody help me with how to calculate the last change in value of some historical table for account balance information.

It has records like below:

```
accountid     balanceAmount      InsertDate
----------------------------------------------
7282991         200             9/6/2015 0:00
7282991         200             9/5/2015 0:00
7282991         100             9/4/2015 0:00
7282991         100             9/3/2015 0:00
7282991         100             9/2/2015 0:00
929999911       500             9/6/2015 0:00
929999911       500             9/5/2015 0:00
929999911       400             9/4/2015 0:00
929999911       200             9/3/2015 0:00
```

I need output like

```
accountid         lastChange
-----------------------------
7282991              100
929999911            100
```

Comment: What do you mean by last change in value?

Comment: if you see above example balance amount for accountid 7282991 get changed on 9/5/2015 from 100 to 200.So the last most recent change in balance amount is : 200 - 100=100. Similarly for 929999911

Comment: Try to be more specific and also include code that you've tried so far.. It would be easier for other to help you...

Comment: @ChupChapCharli: which version of sql server?.

Comment: @TFrost: Suppose you have some banking account whose balance get change in day 2 day transactions. I am saving the account historical data in a table and want to know when did balance amount get changed and by what amount ?Above example shows the basic structure of that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prepare data**

```
create table #records(accountid varchar(100),balanceamount int,insertdate datetime)

insert into #records values
('7282991',200,'9/6/2015'),
('7282991',200,'9/5/2015'),
('7282991',100,'9/4/2015'),
('7282991',100,'9/3/2015'),
('7282991',100,'9/2/2015'),
('929999911',500,'9/6/2015'),
('929999911',500,'9/5/2015'),
('929999911',400,'9/4/2015'),
('929999911',200,'9/3/2015')
```

**Query**

```
with cte1 as
(
   SELECT accountid,
          balanceamount,
          insertdate,
          balanceamount-LEAD(balanceamount) OVER (partition by accountid 
                                               ORDER BY insertdate desc) as 
    change
   FROM #records
),
cte2 as
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by accountid 
                           ORDER BY insertdate desc) as rn, 
    * 
   from cte1 
   where change<>0
)

select accountid,
       change 
from cte2 
where rn=1
```